# How can I stop my Kobo Glo from selecting a book for me?

Tags: kobo, kobo-glo

When I have finished a book but not started a new one, and then my ereader goes to sleep, it opens a new book (seemingly at random) so it has a cover to display on the sleeping screen (as I have selected the "show cover" option when sleeping). This messes me up because I like to have the books I've read marked as Finished when I am done with them so I know what's been read, but this means books will randomly become 1% read.

Is there a way to tell the reader to show a cover only if I have a book I am actively reading, and to just show a blank screen or something if I'm between books?